# CKEditor simple image upload functionality

Tags: 6, media, wysiwyg, files

I'd like to have a simple, one-click, image upload functionality with CKEditor. I'm using D6 and CKEditor 3.6.1. I do not want a server file browsing functionality, only uploading images from the user's own computer.

I've done a thorough search on this subject and have tried different suggested approaches. It seems like the solution that best suits my needs is installing the IMCE module and the CKFinder plugin for the CKEditor module. So I did just that, and followed the installation instructions found here: http://drupal.org/node/738092

The uploaded image manages to get to the destination folder on my server, but when I open CKEditor's 'Image properties' dialog and hit the 'Send to the server' button, nothing changes on the UI.

What I wish to happen is for CKEditor to close the 'Image' dialog and insert the uploaded image into the textarea.

Here are some screenshots to better explain my situation:

**- Uploading a file from my desktop**

[image: Uploading a file from my desktop]

**- Expected result - 'Image' dialog automatically closed and image inserted to textarea**

[image: Expected result - 'Image' dialog automatically closed and image inserted to textarea]

**- Actual result - 'Image' dialog stays open and nothing changes**

[image: Actual result - 'Image' dialog stays open and nothing changes]

Does anyone ever implemented an image upload functionality this way? Is there a better way to get what I want?

Comment: If you solved your problem, please post it as an answer, instead of editing into the question, and mark as accepted once the allotted amount of time has passed

Answer (score 4):

If you ever get to D7, this module does exactly what you're looking for:

[One Click Upload module](https://drupal.org/project/ocupload)

> Button for BUEditor and CKEditor which allows upload files in one click.
>
> Features
>
> - Upload images and insert into editor image code
> - Upload files and insert into editor link code
> - Multi-upload files and images
> - Integration with image styles
> - Editable html templates

Comment: It is very useful, but the image uploaded cannot be resized.

Comment: This is the correct answer. @Sithu, if you click on the uploaded image and open image property box by clicking to the image icon on CKEditor toolbar, you can set image size and other properties.

Answer (score 1):

Now [CKUtils Image](http://doksoft.com/soft/ckutils/image-upload.html) plugin is available right for this thing!
See also another plugins from set, for example [to upload previews](http://doksoft.com/soft/ckutils/preview-upload.html) with link to full-sized image.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [One time Upload Module](https://drupal.org/project/ocupload) in order to full fill your need if you wish to use Drupal 7 version.

> Features:
>
> 1. Upload images and insert into editor image code
> 2. Upload files and insert into editor link code
> 3. Multi-upload files and images
> 4. Integration with image styles
> 5. Editable html templates

For more detail about the module you could read the README.txt of this module.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try the the following plugin which allows you to directly upload files to the server without needing any file browser. Great and simply the best experiences you will get!

http://doksoft.com/soft/ckutils/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dragndrop_uploads](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_uploads) module. It provides versions for both Drupal 7 and Drupal 6, the latter are just hidden behind the "[View all releases" link](https://www.drupal.org/node/629276/release), probably because they are unsupported now.

Despite the name, it's not a generic file upload module but made for image uploading into rich text editors. From the [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_uploads):

> The Drag'n'Drop Uploads module adds the ability to drag an image from your local filesystem, drop it onto a node body textarea and have the file automatically uploaded and referenced in your node. […] [It provides] Support for the WYSIWYG module.

Answer (score -3):

To upload an image, simply drag-and-drop from your desktop or from anywhere. You can also copy the image and paste it on the text area using ctrl+v.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Does this answer relate to the question in any way? Are you saying that CKeditor has a built-in feature to allow HTML5 drag/drop of files from the local file system? If so could you expand on where you've got that information from please?

Comment: Dragging the image and dropping it on the form element doesn't automatically upload the image, nor does it close the dialog box.