# How to enable drag and drop picture upload into CKEditor?

Tags: wysiwyg, media

I would like to include the functionality of drag & drop image uploading in CKEditor of my Drupal webpage.

I have been looking for information about that but I can't find anything useful, have you ever done it? I hope you can help me.

Comment: Seems here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10383/ckeditor-simple-image-upload-functionality something similar to your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Most drag&drop upload solutions are meant for image / file upload fields, but there is one more that integrates with CKEditor: the [media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media) module. According to its [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/media):

> Features: […] Drag and drop upload (requires the [Plupload](https://www.drupal.org/project/plupload) module).

Choose the 7.x-2.x branch, it [reportedly](https://www.drupal.org/project/plup) has better drag&drop image upload capabilities. Integration of media with CKEditor happens via the [wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module, so if you deploy CKEditor instead via the ckeditor or editor modules, it may not work even if overriding dependencies, because these integrations have slightly differing APIs to talk to CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

The [dragndrop_uploads](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_uploads) module is made exactly for your purpose. Despite the name, it's not a generic file upload module but made for image uploading into rich text editors. From the [project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/dragndrop_uploads):

> The Drag'n'Drop Uploads module adds the ability to drag an image from your local filesystem, drop it onto a node body textarea and have the file automatically uploaded and referenced in your node. […] [It provides] Support for the WYSIWYG module.

Note that "Support for the WYSIWYG module" means that drag&drop upload will work if you install CKEditor via the [wysiwyg](https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module, but *probably* not when you install it via the [ckeditor](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor) or (the new favourite) the [editor](https://www.drupal.org/project/editor) module. They all have slightly differing APIs.